# Show id when selecting a checkbox

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a couple of checkboxes, two of these need to show some fields covered by an ID.

I have it working for one ID but I need to have it working for 2 IDs.

Here is my working example for the first checkbox, it also needs to work for the second one: http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/nane902a/1/

This is my code:

```
var checkDisplay = function(check, sl) {
    form = document.getElementById(sl), check = document.getElementById(check);
    check.onclick = function(){
        form.style.display = (this.checked) ? "block" : "none";
        form.reset();
    };
    check.onclick();
};

checkDisplay("check", "sl");
```

Comment: Do you need to show the same form for both checkboxes?

Comment: yes, when checking: checkbox 1, checkbox 2 or both then that div needs to be visible. its not really a form I need to show but some fields. The fields are into a span id="sl"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add classes to the checkboxes, to make the JavaScript a bit more compact and also easily let you add additional checkboxes to in the mix.

Something like this:

```
var frm = document.getElementById('sl');
var check = document.getElementsByClassName('showsubform');
for (var i = 0, length = check.length; i < length; i++) {
    check[i].addEventListener('click', function() { frm.style.display = (this.checked) ? "block" : "none"; });   
}
```

I edited [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nane902a/9/) and created a working example there.

If you prefer to use `onclick`, for IE8 support, you can just replace the `addEventListener` with:

```
check[i].onclick = function() { frm.style.display = (this.checked) ? "block" : "none"; };
```

Comment: This is perfect, very clean. Thanks Mackan!

Comment: You're welcome @iMarc. A note: I chose to use `addEventListener` over `onclick`, but you should be aware that this is not supported for IE8 and below. It can easily be replaced by an onclick though: `check[i].onclick = function() { frm.style.display = (this.checked) ? "block" : "none"; }`. Use what you prefer, the result will be the same for anything over IE8 :)

Answer (score 0):

For the second check box, `checkDisplay("check2", "sl");`

However, you need to remove `form.reset()` from the `onClick` function. It errors and, thus, halts the script execution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the class attribute to identify your checkboxes. Then attach the onclick event to all of them. Example is this jsfiddle:

```
    var checkDisplay = function() {
        var form = document.getElementById('sl');
        var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('yourClass');
        for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
            checks[i].onclick = function(){
                form.style.display = (this.checked) ? "block" : "none";
                form.reset();
            };
        }
    };

checkDisplay();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nane902a/8/

Comment: Thank you, there is a little bug in this, when checking both, then uncheck the second one it doesn't display while it should because the first is checked. I now use Pawel's version. thanks again.